# How to add properties to ApplicationUser in AspNetCore Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

(This question will be self answered, as I have not found a good answer to it on searching. If there is an existing answer, please let me know.)

How do I add a property to ApplicationUser which is stored in the AspNetUsers table?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question is so easy that it gets missed:

First, add it to the database, then add it to the ApplicationUser class:

```csharp
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int TenantId{ get; set; }
}
```

This is all you need to do to add TenantId.  Now, when you need to know the TenantId of a user, just use the UserManager as usual:

```csharp
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
```

The returned user will have the TenantId populated from the database.

You can save updated custom properties with this:

```csharp
await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

That's it.

Comment: Your answer works fine, but I don't see where to store this field using the ManageController. The build-in Identity fields have async methods for updating them when the user edits his or her profile, but I'm not seeing an easy and obvious way of doing that.

Comment: @CMPalmer, I have edited my answer.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes, thanks! We figured it out, but it wasn't clear at first.

Comment: Man you are a GEM! In my manage profile page, on Post method, there are SetEmailAsync and SetPhoneNumberAsync methods being used for updating email and phone. If I use UpdateAsync for updating additional properties, will that affect email or phone?

Comment: @HamzaKhanzada,  I think you can use either SetEmailAsync, or UpdateAsync - they do the same thing.  Test and see to know for sure :)